# Rails 3 /devise seems to ignore custom controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, routes, devise

Using devise with Rails 3 app, I have read wiki/docs on how to customise the after sign up route, I am using confirmable module, so I think I need to override after_inactive_sign_up_path_for

I think I've done it all right, but it is completely ignoring my custom controller and still routing to the root_path after sign up. Driving me nuts.

My registration is using User model, I have copied the views for devise using the generate task; if i move them to views/registrations devise falls back to the default views (in the gem I guess), so it seems not to be 'noticing' my controller

I have this in my routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
match 'sign_up_done' => 'home#sign_up_done', :as => :after_sign_up
```

Here is my controller: (controllers/registrations_controller.rb)

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    after_sign_up_path
  end 
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
   after_sign_up_path
  end
end
```

(Added after_sign_up_path_for just in case, using confirmable)

It just seems to completely ignore my controller, is the naming wrong?
Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your folder structure may have problems. try this structure:  ( it's the same as those in Gem folder)

```
app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb
app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb
```

and the controller file looks the same as it is declared in the gem folder:

```
#app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

# NOT: class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController  , 
# since you are "overwriting" it. 
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    #...
  end 
end
```

Comment: With this setup I get: Expected .../app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb to define Devise::RegistrationsController

Comment: I figured out eventually that I had a duplicate line in my routes file: "devise_for :users" which was the first line added by the generator; I didn't see it as my view was scrolled and obviously in routes higher placed lines override lower ones. This is why it was ignoring my custom controller as this was defined on the lower line.